# yii CListView is not updating when we delete the records through ajax request

Tags: yii

here i am using the ajax request to delete the record from the clistview the record is deleting succesfully but the list view is not updating if we refresh the page then only the record is removing from the clist view can any one help here is my code

```
<?php
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Delete'), $this->createUrl('delete', array('id' => $data['id'])), array(// for htmlOptions
            'onclick' => ' {' . CHtml::ajax(array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))return true;else return false;}',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('delete', array('id' => $data['id'],'ajax'=>'delete')),
            'complete'=>'js:function(jqXHR, textStatus){$.fn.yiiListView.update("firstlist");}'
            )) .
            'return false;}', // returning false prevents the default navigation to another url on a new page 
            )
        );
```

here is the code for clistview

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'id' => 'firstlist', 
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_beneview',
            'enablePagination' => false,
            'summaryText' => '',

)); ?>
```

Comment: Could you include the code for the `CListView`?

Comment: Using Firebug or a similar tool, is the `$.fn.yiiListView.update(...` executing? If it is, is the result as expected?

Comment: Instead of CHtml::link, you can try CHtml::ajaxLink, maybe it work

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CHtml::ajaxLink` for ajax request, but your way is also fine.
I have filtered CListView results also with paginations enabled, you can just look at the major things for updating list view on [this link](http://phpsoftsol.chandigarhservices.com/yii-clistview-ajax-search/)

Please check view part and updating script part.
Hope his will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use CGridView, you can add CButtonColumn